# Minimum Edits for Two Strings

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to use dynamic programming to determine the minimum edits required on one string

1. to transform it into another string
2. The code below does this, but I'm trying to find a way to keep track of the edits (`d=delete, r=replace, i=insert`).

For example:

**string 1: sunflower**

```
d rrrr    <---Changes applying to string 1 (tracking minimum edits necessary to transform it into string 2)
```

**string 2: sunlight**

I'm not certain how to accomplish this, but I suspect it might have something to do with backtracking through the minimum distance table which is created. The code below finds the minimum distance perfectly fine, but I'm not certain how to approach keeping track of the necessary edits. Any ideas?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

#define INSERT_COST 1
#define DELETE_COST 1
#define REPLACE_COST 1

using namespace std;

int min(int a,int b) {
   return ((a < b) ? a : b);
}

/* convert str1 to str2 with minimum edits(insert,delete,replace)
   suppose length(str1) = m and length(str2) = n
   cost(i,j) -> cost of converting str1[0...i-1] to str2[0...j-1]
   cost(m,n) -> cost of converting str1 to str2 
   Standard recursive formula for computing cost(m,n) :-
   cost(i,j) = min[cost(i-1,j)+D, cost(i,j-1)+I, cost(i-1,j-1)+R]
   D -> delete cost, I -> insert cost, R -> replace cost  */

int editDistance(char str1[],int size1,char str2[],int size2) {
   // cost matrix
   // row -> str1 & col -> str2
   int cost[size1][size2];
   int i,j;
   // initialize the cost matrix
   for (i=0;i<size1;i++) {
      for(j=0;j<size2;j++) {
         if (i == 0) {
            // source string is NULL
            // so we need 'j' insert operations
            cost[i][j] = j*INSERT_COST;
         } else if (j == 0) {
            // target string is NULL
            // so we need 'i' delete operations
            cost[i][j] = i*DELETE_COST;
         } else {
            cost[i][j] = -1;
         }
      }
   } //initialization done

   //compute cost(i,j) and eventually return cost(m,n)
   for(i=1;i<size1;i++) {
      for(j=1;j<size2;j++) {
         int x = cost[i-1][j] + DELETE_COST;
         int y = cost[i][j-1] + INSERT_COST;
         // if str1(i-1) != str2(j-1), add the replace cost
         // we are comparing str1[i-1] and str2[j-1] since
         // the array index starts from 0
         int z = cost[i-1][j-1] + (str1[i-1] != str2[j-1])*REPLACE_COST;
         // as per our recursive formula
         cost[i][j] = min(x, min(y,z));
      }
   }

   // last cell of the matrix holds the answer
   return cost[size1-1][size2-1];
}

//main
int main() {
   char str1[] = "sunflower";
   char str2[] = "sunlight";
   int size1 = strlen(str1);
   int size2 = strlen(str2);
   int min_cost = editDistance(str1,size1+1,str2,size2+1);
   cout<<"\nMinimum edits required to convert "<<str1<<
                                       " to "<<str2<<" is "<<min_cost;
   cout<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: A fairly common edit distance function is the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Please don't just dump your code here. Ask a specific question instead. Post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) and let us know if you experience a compile or run time error.

Comment: I tried to ask a specific question. The code above works fine for finding the minimum distance, but I'm not certain how to approach keeping track of the necessary edits.

Comment: This is not standard c++.. `int cost[size1][size2];` cannot be done. `size1` and `size2` are parameters and requires an extension (gcc one for VLAs) or use of alloca. Anyway, for keeping track, use an `std::tuple`. You can make it hold string one, string two, and the edit distance. Otherwise create your own `struct` to do so. If you mean keeping track of every edit required to transform one string into another, my suggestion above is thus invalid.

Comment: It may not be standard C++, but the algorithm works. I need to keep track of every edit required to transform one string to another (as illustrated in the example above).

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames, it's actually standard since C++14.

Comment: trying seeing Least Common Subsequence problem from "Introduction to Algorithms: Thomas H. Cormen, ...". The technique described there would work perfectly. I could have explained that here but somehow i cannot ans to this question, just comment is allowed.